# Cannot Delete ENI - RDS Already Deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I tried to deploy code to an ElasticBeanstalk environment. Every-time I try to deploy this branch to an environment EB kills all instances, ELB, RDS, etc and tries to rebuild but fails. This leaves the environment in a bad state because it deletes the RDS but does not delete the security groups or ENI. When I try to delete the security groups manually it fails saying there are dependant objects.

I traced it back to the network interface but when I try to detach it (even force detach) I get an error that I do not have permission. This ENI should have been removed with the RDS instance but it was not. Now I cannot get rid of the environment at all and cannot rebuild it.

I am not sure why this application would cause the environment to attempt to re-create everything upon every deployment as the EC2 instances go away and then when they load back up they are added to the ELB however the ELB cannot do the health checks so they are constantly put Out of Service and the environment is in a dead state. It would be nice if I could somehow see the logs as to what is causing the environments to crash with this application.

Having ElasticBeanstalk delete all instances including RDS is not acceptable for a deployment because we constantly have to re-seed this, not to mention if this were ever deployed to production it would wipe all production data and we cannot have that.

Is there a way to see what is going on during a deployment and why this may be happening?

Comment: EB should not be terminating environments during a deployment. Are you seeing anything unusual on the Events tab in the EB console? Perhaps an auto-scaling rule is triggering and terminating your instance?

Comment: This is the log, you can see everything that happens during the deployment leading the environment to fail because the newly created ec2 instance is seen by the ELB to be OutOfService for some odd reason.  This happens with every deployment even when I rebuild the environment from scratch.  https://paste.laravel.io/LKLzq

Currently, I have an environment in a stuck state because I tried to manually terminate and it would not. I cannot manually delete the ENI either as it says I do not have permission because the termination process already deleted the RDS instance

Comment: This is the log from when I tried to rebuild the environment after the deployment failed and new instances were initialized but not able to communicate with the ELB  https://paste.laravel.io/KLoRw  In the end I cannot delete the security groups because of the ENI and I cannot detach the ENI due to RDS being deleted already.

Comment: My main goals are to get this environment removed and figure out why on deployment each time it tries to remove the EC2 instance, create another and the new one cannot communicate with the ELB.

Comment: It looks as if the environment termination isn't directly related to the deployment - there's a 30-second gap between when your deployment finished and when the termination began. Additionally, it appears that the termination began because the health check failed. How is your health check configured? Does it ever show your instance's state as `Ok`?

Comment: Yes when I create the environment all is ok.  The reason I think it has something to do with the deployment is because this code is in a seperate branch than what is currently running on our dev environment.  As soon as I deploy this branch it goes haywire.  If I deploy our development branch all is fine.  This code is for setting up a worker environment as we are trying to migrate to using a queue and worker environment for processing queued items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk uses CloudFormation behind the scenes. You will be able to delete the entire environment by identifying the correct stacks (prefixed by `awseb-e-j5zfptidfe-stack` according to your logs) and removing them - or at least removing the one with the ENI.

You will also need to remove the environment from within ElasticBeanstalk. This will reset everything. If there are dependent stacks - like with the security groups. The best solution is to read the messages to determine the dependencies and clean those up first.

It is good practice to not include your RDS in the elastic beanstalk stack if you know you will want to preserve the data in it. Create this separately and just pass in the connection details to your stack. AWS provide [detailed instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html). A short summary would be:

1. Create a security group for the database
2. Create an RDS database with the security group
3. Add the database connection paremeters as environment variables to your EB stack
4. Add the EC2 security group to your database security group as an allowed source of traffic to the db.

Finally. You need to determine why the instances are being terminated in your stack. It looks like they are not becoming 'healthy'. Disable `Ignore health check` which is an option for Elastic Beanstalk deployments.

This should result in an environment with EC2 instances marked 'unhealthy'. You can then use whatever tools you need to, to diagnose why the EC2 instances are not correctly responding to the `health checks` and resolve the issue.

There could be many reasons the EC2 instance fails the health check. The check itself could be incorrectly configured, security groups could be wrong or the service on the EC2 instance itself may not be responding as it should.

Comment: I will look into deleting the stack based on what you stated, however deleting the environment from inside beanstalk fails every time I try to terminate it.  I have found what is causing the issue and it is a configuration file adding a security group ingress rule, I have removed that file for the time being and it seems to work.  The file I was using is this one here, not sure why it was failing. https://github.com/FoxxMD/laravel-elasticbeanstalk-queue-worker/blob/master/src/.ebextensions/00supervisordIngress.config

Comment: @JosephCrawford, the file creates a resource 'AWSEBSecurityGroup' which may [already exist](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html). If that file is merged with the ElasticBeanstalk stack then two resources with the same name would result in undefined behaviour.